# eBay API reviseItem call using Java SDK

Tags: java, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I have two `ItemType` objects: `oldItem` and `newItem`. I would like to `Revise` the `oldItem` to reflected changes in the `newItem`. To do this I assume after reading the [documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseItem.html) that we need to provide a list of removed/deleted fields.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way to go through all the fields (that can be changed) in the `newItem`, compare it to the `oldItem` and then actually come up with a string array of fields that was removed in the revision. And perhaps return and empty array of strings if no field was deleted.

PS. Let me know if my initial assumption about providing eBay with a list of deleted fields is incorrect. If that is incorrect then I am gonna have a much easier time revising items through the API.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://developer.ebay.com/developercenter/java/ ?